# UIScrollView with content view - Autolayout issue

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have an issue in adding constraints on my subviews inside a scrollview. I iterate through an array of UIViews and there is a conflict on my final object in the array. The constraint breaks. Here is the [code](http://pastebin.com/VV3gyTy1) to reproduce this issue.

Can someone guide me here?

Console Log:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8195006be0 UIScrollView:0x7f8195006320.height == UIView:0x7f8195005be0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8195019760 V:|-(0)-[UIScrollView:0x7f8195006320]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f81950180d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8195019850 V:[UIScrollView:0x7f8195006320]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f8195018fc0]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f8195004b80 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f8195018fc0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f81950008c0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f8195018fc0.bottom == UIView:0x7f81950180d0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3c540 V:[UIButton:0x7f819500dc40'Test Btn 0'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3d040 V:|-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819500dc40'Test Btn 0']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f8195005be0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3d8f0 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501a7d0'Test Btn 1'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3e270 V:[UIButton:0x7f819500dc40'Test Btn 0']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501a7d0'Test Btn 1']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3e4c0 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501abf0'Test Btn 2'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3ec10 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501a7d0'Test Btn 1']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501abf0'Test Btn 2']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3f040 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501ae10'Test Btn 3'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3f5d0 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501abf0'Test Btn 2']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501ae10'Test Btn 3']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3faa0 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b030'Test Btn 4'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e40040 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501ae10'Test Btn 3']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501b030'Test Btn 4']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e40380 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b250'Test Btn 5'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e40d50 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b030'Test Btn 4']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501b250'Test Btn 5']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e410b0 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b470'Test Btn 6'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e41720 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b250'Test Btn 5']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501b470'Test Btn 6']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e41aa0 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b690'Test Btn 7'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3f500 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b470'Test Btn 6']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501b690'Test Btn 7']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e42410 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b8b0'Test Btn 8'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3feb0 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b690'Test Btn 7']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501b8b0'Test Btn 8']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e42d70 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501bad0'Test Btn 9'(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3b030 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b8b0'Test Btn 8']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501bad0'Test Btn 9']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e32bd0 UIButton:0x7f819501bad0'Test Btn 9'.bottom == UIView:0x7f8195005be0.bottom + 100>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e442b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7f81950180d0(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3b030 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b8b0'Test Btn 8']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501bad0'Test Btn 9']>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Please add the console output which tells you what constraint was broken and why.

Comment: I added a test code to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem here is that you haven't initialized your terminalUIElements array. I can't find it in your code.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8192e3b030 V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b8b0'Test Btn 8']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501bad0'Test Btn 9']>
```

Try adding this to your constraint.

```
V:[UIButton:0x7f819501b8b0'Test Btn 8']-(130)-[UIButton:0x7f819501bad0'Test Btn 9']-|;
```

Comment: Make sure you have all the four directions covered for all the views. Inside a scroll view when you use auto layout the content size is calculated with the help of the subviews constraints. You do not need to give the content size. The last subview should define the distance from the bottom of the superview also. So that it covers all the four sides for the auto layout constraints.

Also you don't need to put the round brackets. V:|-0-[view]-0-|. This will work too.